# Why does the Federal Reserve seem to hold so much weight on the unemployment rate, relative to labor participation?

Tags: labor-economics, interest-rate, federal-reserve, unemployment

The title is the question.

In the press conference [held yesterday](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMuuLoMPXTc), the Chair referenced "unemployment" 18 times, relative to "participation" 3 times.  If the labor participation is at the [lowest since the 70's](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/12309/has-the-way-unemployment-is-measured-changed-in-the-last-8-years), is it delusional to buy into the seemingly marketed strength of the U.S. economy?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the press conference, other data is taken into consideration, such as the [Employment - Population Ratio](http://data.bls.gov/pdq/SurveyOutputServlet), especially when filtered/line series graphed to detail trends in demographics.

[This blog post](http://qz.com/286213/the-chart-obama-haters-love-most-and-the-truth-behind-it/) provides a bit more insight on the data.

It seems relatively, the U.S. is climbing to employment-pop levels we haven't seen since the mid 80's, which seems to suggest the outlook isn't as terrible as initially thought.